API Gateway response not showing Lambda error response (python)
I have the following lambda exception snippet:
    except Exception as e:
        response['statusCode'] = 500
        response['body'] = "Fatal Error"
        
        raise Exception(json.dumps(response))

but the response I get from my API GW is:
{
    "code": "...",
    "description": "...",
    "log_trace": "..."
}

with messages in the ...
But it doesn't display my own body message. How can I pass this through or have it respond with e.g "Fatal Error"
It seems to map correctly to my integration response but the mapping template is below for my 400 errors:
$input.path('$.errorMessage');

